# iOS development starts level. How I can use for_in for request API

Tags: swift, request

iOS development starts level. How I can use for_in for request API.

I mean I have a code :

```
import UIKit

var ipName = ["192.168.1.0"..."192.168.1.254"] 
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://192.168.1.1/")!)
for i in ipName {
    print("It's, \(i)")     }
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
print(String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self))
print(response)
print(error)
}
task.resume()
```

and I need to query all addresses from my network and select all who are connected ("for example" out of 254 addresses).

P.S - Sorry for my English.

Comment: You can't create a range like that, make an Int range for the last part of the IP address, `let range = 1...254` and then build a string from it `ipAddress = "192.168.1.\(i)` in your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this, a numeric range and then String Interpolation to build the IP

```
let ipRange = 0...254
for i in ipRange {
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.\(i)")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }
        print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "No readable string")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Hello Vadian! Thanks for your quick reply! But from the loop for in, it is impossible to get the variable "ip". What did I do wrong?
  
import UIKit
//var ipRange = [0...254]
var request1 = "http://192.168.1."
for i in (0...254) {
    let ip = "\(request1)\(i)"
//    print("\(ip)")
}
print(i)
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(ip.())")!)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
print(String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self))
print(response)
print(error)
}
task.resume()

Comment: Please read my answer closely: `"(request1)(i)"` is not equal to `"192.168.1.\(i)"`. You could use `ip = request1 + String(i)`. And there is no need to put `0..254` in parentheses

Comment: Yea, for_in is working. But I don't understand how I can get (constant "ip") for my request to the server.

var ipName = 0...254
for i in ipName {
    let ip = "192.168.1.\(i)"
//    print(ip)
}

print(ip)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://192.168.1.1/")!)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
print(String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self))
print(response)
print(error)
}
task.resume()

Thank you for your time you really help me!

Comment: please see my edit.